# Installing Ardor3D. I can't even run the examples

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ardor3d

I'm pretty new to Java, and thought that using 3D graphics would be interesting. I found Ardor 3D and installed it, etc. I followed the steps from [here](https://github.com/Renanse/Ardor3D/wiki/Getting-started-with-Git-and-Eclipse).

But when I ran the example code, such as `ExampleRunner.java`, it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ardor3d/example/ExampleRunner
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ardor3d.example.ExampleRunner    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

I've looked everywhere for solutions to this error, but I can't find anyone else who has it.

Comment: Most probably you haven't installed some package or dependency with com.ardor3d.example.ExampleRunner class.

Comment: Do you have any idea what that would be? I downloaded it from GitHub through Eclipse. I don't know how I would have missed something.

Comment: Or maybe the example jar is not in the directory with other files or where else it should be.

Comment: Sorry, my inexperience is going to be obvious here. How would I check that? Where would I find the .jar? I know the intro tutorial from Ardor3d (https://github.com/Renanse/ardor3d/wiki/Your-First-Steps) didn't mention anything about .jar files.

Comment: No more ideas. Try posting an issue maybe: https://github.com/Renanse/Ardor3D/issues

Comment: Ensure that you have built it at least once with M2Eclipse. Anyway, you use an obsolete abandoned version of Ardor3D: http://blog.renanse.com/2014/03/winding-down.html http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Overview http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

At first, ensure that your Eclipse install supports Maven, you should install M2Eclipse if necessary.

Then, you use an obsolete and unmaintained version of Ardor3D, Renanse stopped maintaining it more than a year ago:
http://blog.renanse.com/2014/03/winding-down.html

You should switch to JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation which is actively maintained by the JogAmp community. I'm responsible for engine support. You can find more information about it here:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Overview
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Tutorial